# ConEmu and linux's screen

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen, conemu

Recently I've stared using ConEmu and it's great. But I encountered one problem that stops me from using it as an ssh client.
When I ssh to a remote machine linux's 'screen' doesn't work very well.

I mean I cannot even go through the list of open sessions in screen. When I do Ctrl+a " I see the list but when I press an arrow to navigate it goes back to the terminal.

This happens when I use it via cygwin.

When I use cmd, I ssh to a machine, run screen, but then when I do ctrl+a to access screen options instead of going to screen I see:

```
[someuser@my-remote ~]$ ^A
```

Screen works properly when I use MobaXTerm.

I haven't found anything about problems with screen and conemu.

Comment: Words "via cygwin" are ambiguous. Anyway, this is a bug of ssh.exe, ConEmu do not do anything with ssh at all. Also, https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsys.html

Comment: I meant I open a cygwin terminal in conemu and then do ssh

Comment: Your cygwin terminal is mintty or not? If any problems appears in mintty, they do not relate to ConEmu.

Comment: In tasks in ConEmu I have configured cygwin as: E:\tools\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe

Maybe this problem isn't related with conemu at all. I tried various ssh clients and couldn't make screen working correctly.

Comment: Exactly. https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsys.html From time to time I think about making some console improvements in [plink](https://github.com/Maximus5/plink)...

Comment: ssh works correctly with git-bash with cygwin and Moba Xterm. When I ssh in with cmder to my vagrant ssh I have no arrow keys or backspace. Ctl-Shift V BackSpace gives the correct ^? for my tyyl.

This is an issue with ConEmu and Cmder.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
export TERM=vt100
```

For some reason conemu and cmder do not send a terminal announcement (This is my guess). In order for you to get a correct terminal use TERM to declare it for you.